# PHP: Stored value in a text file and printed one in view file is not the same

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my controller, there are three methods:
**NOTICE:** I use Codeigniter v3...

```
public funtion index(){
 $data['code'] = $this->generate_random_string();

 $myfile = fopen("C:\wamp\www\write.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
 fwrite($myfile, $data['code']);
 fclose($myfile);

 $this->load->view('path_to_view/view1', $data);
}

//$param is numeric
public funtion send($param){
 $data['code'] = $this->generate_random_string();

 $myfile = fopen("C:\wamp\www\write.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
 fwrite($myfile, $data['code']);
 fclose($myfile);

 $this->load->view('path_to_view/view2', $data);
}

public function generate_random_string(){
 $this->load->helper('string');
 $date = new DateTime();        

 return random_string('sha1', 40) . $date->getTimestamp();
}
```

in the first and second method, I generate a random string, assign it to $data['code'] and also save it in a file (write.txt), and then load a view and echo $data['code'].
**The problem is:** in first method, stored $data['code'] in file and printed one in view file is the same, but in second method (send) they are different!!!
Another thing to say is: when I add below statement in second method and print value in controller (instead of view), everything will be ok:
   var_dump($data['code']);

I could not understand what happened! There is not any special code to affect these, just some loading view, header, footer.

Could anyone help to find possible issues or guess what is ?
thanks.
**SOLVED:** I check all view file, I couldn't find related code to this issue. But, when I comment below line in header, the problem is solved!
   
Could anyone explain about this? just a link element cause problem!

Comment: Not enough info to give a definitive answer, but if `$data['code']` matches the contents of the file when output directly from the controller via `var_dump($data['code']);` but displays non matching content when output via the view, then the issue must lay withing the view file `path_to_view/view2`. Please show the content of the 2 view files for further help

Comment: HI, I have a theory. The views derived from the same object and it could be convert it to the static value. Can you in a send function change  the name of $data to $data1. just to make sure

Comment: You're right. may be it is a bit vague. but the two view files have common shared codes, like header, modals, footer, and... and the different code in each one in nothing except some printing... Why index method is ok, and send acts different! if view is the problem, the two method will be failed. Are you agree? (reply to first comment)

Comment: renaming $data to $data1 not change anything.